# query on MySQL 5 replication

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have a table which contains a large volume of data...thousands of million of rows. I am planning to have a replica of this table. Can I have an index on replica only not on the original table, so that insertion in the orignal table will be fast.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's possible. You can even change the underlying engine of the replicated table (a common scenario is to replicate a InnoDB table to another server, change the engine to MyISAM and add a full-text-index to the appropriate table columns).